What's wrong in this LaplaceTransform?
What's wrong in this LaplaceTransform?
tmps = (4 \[Tau])/((1 + s \[Tau])^2 (8 s (Kp + M s^2) Cosh[s] + 
            4 s^2 Sinh[s] + 4 (Kp + M s^2)^2 Sinh[s])) 

tmpt = InverseLaplaceTransform[tmps, s, t, Assumptions -> {\[Tau] > 0}] 
    
tmps2= FullSimplify[LaplaceTransform[tmpt, t, s, Assumptions -> {\[Tau] > 0}]] 
    
{tmps2, tmps} /. {Kp -> 1, M -> 0.1, \[Tau] -> 0.2, s -> 1}

I'd expected that tmps2==tmps but it is not so. Here is output on my desktop:

(4 \[Tau])/((1 + s \[Tau])^2 (8 s (Kp + M s^2) Cosh[s] +     4 s^2
Sinh[s] + 4 (Kp + M s^2)^2 Sinh[s]))

-((2 E^((   1 - t)/\[Tau]) \[Tau]^3 (E^(
     2/\[Tau]) (M + \[Tau] + 
       Kp \[Tau]^2) (M (1 + t + 4 \[Tau]) + \[Tau] (1 + 
          t + (2 + Kp + Kp t) \[Tau])) - (M + \[Tau] (-1 + 
          Kp \[Tau])) (M (-1 + t + 
          4 \[Tau]) + \[Tau] (1 - (2 + Kp) \[Tau] + 
          t (-1 + Kp \[Tau])))))/(-E^(
     2/\[Tau]) (M + \[Tau] + 
      Kp \[Tau]^2)^2 + (M + \[Tau] (-1 + Kp \[Tau]))^2)^2)

-((2 E^(1/\[Tau]) \[Tau]^4 (E^(
        2/\[Tau]) (M + \[Tau] + Kp \[Tau]^2) (M + \[Tau] + 
          M (5 + s) \[Tau] + (3 + Kp + s + 
             4 M s) \[Tau]^2 + (Kp + (2 + 
                Kp) s) \[Tau]^3) - (M + \[Tau] (-1 + 
             Kp \[Tau])) (\[Tau] - \[Tau]^2 (3 + Kp + 
             Kp (-1 + s) \[Tau] + s (-1 + 2 \[Tau])) + 
          M (-1 + \[Tau] (5 + s (-1 + 4 \[Tau]))))))/((1 + 
       s \[Tau])^2 (-E^(
         2/\[Tau]) (M + \[Tau] + 
          Kp \[Tau]^2)^2 + (M + \[Tau] (-1 + Kp \[Tau]))^2)^2)) 


{-0.000254482, 0.0231792}
Update:
Now I am pretty sure that this is bug. Numerical version of InverseLaplaceTransform yields correct result.

Not sure why, but in the limit as $s \to \infty$ they are the same.  i.e. the larger $s$ is, tmps and tmps2 become closer to each other.  Even though Mathematica says that the ConvergenceRegion for the Laplace transform is $s>-5$. Note also your tmps has singularity at $s=0$. You can see this from Plot[tmps, {s, -1, 1}] using the parameters you had. This could have something to do with it.

@Nasser; tmps has an infinite set of singularities on imaginary axes.

InverseLaplaceTransform[tmps, s, t, Assumptions -> {\[Tau] > 0}] gives wrong answer, probably a Bug !!!.
